# If(Session[loginid]==null)

Tags: asp.net

I am writing in my Page_Load like

```
if(Session[loginid]== null)
```

then redirect to login page or other page.Else populate the list.There is one dropdownlist and 2 button control in my page.Does I need to write

```
if(Session[loginid]== null)
```

in populate list function ,it's selectedindexchange function and button event.Selectedindexchange again call 2 another function inside it.Does I need to write in that function also.

SamplePage.aspx

1 Dropdownlist
2 Button1
3 Button3

SamplePage.aspx.cs

```
1 Page_Load()
2 Populate()
3 ddl_SelectedindexChange()
4 Button1_click()
5 Button2_click()
6 function1()
7 fuction2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Page_Load() do this:

```
if(Session["loginid"]== null)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
}
else
{
    Populate();
}
```

Since the user would be redirected to login page if Session["loginid"] is null, hence no other function would be executed, but the Page_Load of Login.aspx would be called. Hence no need to include the null check in the rest of the functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a base class like this:

```
public class SecurePageBase : System.Web.UI.Page.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["loginid"]== null) 
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
        }   

        base.OnPreInit(e);
    }
}
```

The idea is that you can then create your webpages like this:

```
public partial class DefaultPage : SecurePageBase
```

Then, in the `Pre_Render()` event of your page, call your  `Populate()` routine to populate the list. If the user's session does not contain LoginID, then the user will be redirect back to the login page (in theory :).

Try this out and let me know if it's what you need, else I'll just delete this answer to save time.

Comment: Jason ,I think it is difficult or confusing one.Let me know the another way.

Comment: What specifically is confusing you? This solution is using object oriented principals to share the common functionality (the security lookup) to whatever page inherits from it. This is definitely good practice.